# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.push') React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So this is the error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.push')`

I use React Navigation 5 and. This is my App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, Alert} from 'react-native';

const MyApp = ({navigation}) => {
  return(
    <Button
      onPress={() => navigation.push('Information')}
      title="Get Information"
    />
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

What is the problem? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define `navigation` inside your const `MyApp`!
And you also should import useNavigation

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, Alert} from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const MyApp = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation(); 
  return(
    <Button
      onPress={() => navigation.push('Information')}
      title="Get Information"
    />
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Thanks for your help [Allandiego](https://github.com/allandiego)